# 'Most' v. 'most of' in a sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I know the general rule: when it's said generally, you don't use 'of'; when it's specific, you do. But again, as with pesky articles, the trouble is figuring out when it's specific enough and when it's not (usually, grammar books assume it's obvious and doesn't need clarification — wrong). Is 'EU members' in this example specific enough? It sounds natural without 'of' to my ear.

> most (of) EU members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say either

> Most EU members

or

> Most of **the** EU members

If it's specific enough to use *of*, then it's specific enough to use the definite article too. In this case, we'd be more likely to use *of* and *the* if the group were further qualified, for example

> Most of the EU members that signed the treaty of Antwerp also implement a VAT.

Now we're not talking about most EU members, but most of a certain sub-group that we define.

We can also use *most of* with a possessive article:

> Most of my friends like chocolate

Or in the specific construction "most of all":

> Speaking of ice cream flavors, I like vanilla most of all.

Comment: Why is 'EU members' (without further qualifications) not specific?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev, because you aren't using the definite article (or another determiner) to make it specific.